# How to solve erroneous resize behavior of iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

Upon resizing the browser window I get the resize event but when checking different DOM values like scrollable height etc, the values are wrong and depict the values before the new layout.

Debouncing the resize solves the issue, but it is really unclear what's the minimal time for debouncing as it depends on page complexity.

I found these related links:

https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5040881597939712

https://hackernoon.com/onresize-event-broken-in-mobile-safari-d8469027bf4d

Question is, is there any way to solve this other than debouncing by some arbitrary time?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [community answer](https://medium.com/@nicolasrucine/hi-there-heres-a-working-solution-using-a-reference-dom-element-auto-sized-through-css-before-5826dff16981) for [resize issue](https://hackernoon.com/onresize-event-broken-in-mobile-safari-d8469027bf4d), there's a working solution using a reference DOM element, auto-sized through CSS before "resize" event being trigged. Something like:

> **CSS**

```
html {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

> **JS**

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    rect = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    realSize = { width: rect.width, height: rect.height };
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I use this on a element not covering the whole height/width? Can I just get the element and call `getBoundingClientRect()` on it?

Comment: @Phonolog You're welcome! Yes you can do so by: `document.getElementById('id').getBoundingClientRect());`

Comment: Alright. Could you also add a link to the community answer you're refering to?